# Symfony2 Query to find last working date from Holiday Calender

Tags: postgresql, symfony, datetime, orm, doctrine

I had a calender entity in my project which manages the open and close time of business day of the whole year.
Below is the record of a specific month

```
id   |     today_date      | year | month_of_year | day_of_month  | is_business_day
-------+---------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------------+         
10103 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            1 | t 
10104 | 2016-02-02 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            2 | t
10105 | 2016-02-03 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            3 | t
10106 | 2016-02-04 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            4 | t
10107 | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            5 | t
10108 | 2016-02-06 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            6 | f
10109 | 2016-02-07 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            7 | f
10110 | 2016-02-08 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            8 | t
10111 | 2016-02-09 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |            9 | t
10112 | 2016-02-10 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           10 | t
10113 | 2016-02-11 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           11 | t
10114 | 2016-02-12 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           12 | t
10115 | 2016-02-13 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           13 | f
10116 | 2016-02-14 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           14 | f
10117 | 2016-02-15 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           15 | t
10118 | 2016-02-16 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           16 | t
10119 | 2016-02-17 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           17 | t
10120 | 2016-02-18 00:00:00 | 2016 |             2 |           18 | t
```

I want the get the today_date of last 7 working date. Supporse today_date is `2016-02-18` and date of last 7 working dates as `2016-02-09`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() for this like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t.*,row_number() OVER(order by today_date desc) as rnk
FROM Calender t
WHERE today_date <= current_date 
      AND is_business_day = 't')
WHERE rnk = 7
```

This will give you the row of the 7th business day from todays date

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tagged your question with Doctrine, ORM and Datetime. Were you after a QueryBuilder solution? Maybe this is closer to what you want:

```
$qb->select('c.today_date')
->from(Calendar::class, 'c')
->where("c.today_date <= :today")
->andWhere("c.is_business_day = 't'")
->setMaxResults(7)
->orderBy("c.today_date", "DESC")
->setParameter('today', new \DateTime('now'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME));
```